# git clone --depth using https and bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I would like to be able to run

```
git clone --depth 1 https://bitbucket_server_address/.../myRepo.git
```

I am able to run previous command with ssh protocol and with https without --depth. With https and --depth I get:

```
error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
```

fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: error: RPC failed; HTTP 500 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error
fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: Seems to work for me. Are you sure this isn't a transient issue?

Comment: I don't think so, I can reproduce it on 2 PCs